# Find the images under the transformation $w=f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

(a) For the transformation $w=z+\bar z$ find the image of $D=\{z\in C| |z|=1$ and $Im(z)\geq 0\}$

(b) For the transformation $w=2iz+i$ find the image of $D=\{z\in C| |z|\lt1$ and $Re(z)\gt 0\}$

For (a) let $z=a+ib$, set $D$ this mean semi-circle as image, [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtL9H.png)

let $F$ represented image of  $D$ under transformation $w=z+\bar z, 
\;w=u+iv$

I have

$$u+iv \in F \iff u+iv=z+\bar z\iff u+iv=2a+i0$$

Thus, $-2\leq u\leq 2$ and $v= 0$

Hence image of $D$ As image,[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWiip.png)

For (b) let $z = a+ib$, set $D$ this mean semi-circle as image,  [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Anbgv.png)

let $F$ represented image of $D$ under transformation $w=2iz+i$,$w=u+iv$

I have $\displaystyle w=u+iv \in F \iff |w-i|=|2iz| \iff |w-i|=2|z|\iff \frac{|w-i|}{2}=|z|$

Thus, $\displaystyle \frac{|w-i|}{2} \lt 1 $ then $|w-i| \lt 2$

Hence, $\displaystyle u+iv \in F\iff u^2+(v-1)^2 \lt 4$ and $Im(z)>i$

Therefore image of $D$ as image,[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGcDS.png)(overlap between red and blue color)

Is it correct? I'm not sure please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Still your answer for a is incorrect. If $w=u+iv=2Re(z)=2a+i0$, What is $Im(w)$?

Comment: $Im(w)= 0 $ right?

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your both are not correct.

for (a) just observe what is $z+\bar z?$ It is $2\mathcal Re (z)$. So if $|z|=1$ what are the possible values of  $\mathcal Re (z)$?

also for (b) observe what does the transformation do. multiplying $iz$ rotate $z$ by an angle of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ counterclockwise around the origin. multiplying by $2$, scale $|iz|$ with a factor of $2$. then adding $i$ will shift $2iz$, $1$ unit upward. so what would be the end result?

By the way, your diagrams for Domains are correct. So try to think geometrically.

Comment: Please check my edited, (b) i got the rectangle, is it correct?

Comment: Nope. try this if $D=\{z: |z| \geq 1\ and \ Re(z) \gt 0 \}$ then what is the set $A=\{iz: z \in D\}$

Comment: Then find $B=\{2w: w \in A\}$. Then find $F=\{z+i: z \in B\}$. then $F$ is your range

Comment: Since (b). I got $u^2+(v-1)^2 \lt 4 $ and $Im(z)>0$ Is it right or not?

Comment: @Zera $Im(z) \gt 0$ or $Im(z) \gt i$?

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much...but I don't understand (a) when $w=2Re(z)$ what happened?

Comment: @Zera what you have got there for a is partially correct. that is $-2 \leq u \leq 2$. But what about the $v$?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution for $(a)$ is not correct.
My hint would be to notice that $z+\overline{z} = 2\Re(z)$ for all $z\in\Bbb C$.

The solution for $(b)$ is also not correct. My hint would be to take it in strides.

1. What is the visual/geometrical effect of the transformation $z \mapsto iz$?
2. What is the visual/geometrical effect of the transformation $z \mapsto 2z$?
3. What is the visual/geometrical effect of the transformation $z \mapsto z + i$?

Figure out each of them and apply them to your initial domain $D$ in succession.

Comment: Your edit for $(a)$ is still incorrect because you failed to consider what values $v$ can take. Your edit for $(b)$ is very far from the answer;  you are approaching this the wrong way by trying to describe the set in terms of simple inequalities $u_0 < u <u_1$ and $v_0 < v < v_1$. Notice that these inequalities, for instance, cannot describe a circle.